# Задание на рекурсию без передачи параметра в функцию

Tags: c++, функции, рекурсия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать, если при придется вводить значение в самой функции и при каждой итерации рекурсии программа будет запрашивать ввод числа. Или я не правильно понял ограничения в задаче?

Comment: Как я понимаю, каждый рекурсивный вызов читает одно число с клавиатуры. Далее все предельно просто...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все не просто просто, а очень просто...

```
int maxi()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 0) return n;
    int m = maxi();
    return (m > n) ? m : n;
}
```

Comment: На вход идет число, например 345430, программа должна выдать 5 как максимальное значение в последовательности, понятно что алгоритм самой задачи очень простой, но что делать, если при каждом шаге рекурсии вводится новое число

Comment: На вход не может идти одно число :) Вы должны вводить по одному числу в строке, как сказано в условии - 3, в следующей - 4, в следующей - 5... Но вы можете даже вводить через пробел, все равно сработает. А вообще, не давайте условия картинкой - это правилами сайта *очень* не приветствуется. Да и отвечать неудобно - так бы я скопировал ваш же текст и ткнул вас в него, а так - набирать нужно...

Comment: Хорошо, а если необходимо чтобы число было в том виде, котором я указал, то такая задача не решается рекурсивно без параметров в функции?

Comment: Да решается, читать только нужно один символ. Просто в вашем варианте - с чего вы решили, что это 3,4,5,4,3, а не 34,5,43, например?...